# Rails flexirest model is deconstructing array of 2 objects into an object with 2 properties with an array each

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this weird error where my flexirest model is being called with

```
{
  "people" => [
    {"name" => "Jane", "age" => 33},
    {"name" => "John", "age" => 36}
  ]
}
```

When the receiving end (node) gets

```
{
  "people": {
    "name": ["Jane", "John"],
    "age": [33, 36]
  }
}
```

I know it's not the receiving service, because a postman request shows the correct structure. Any idea what might have gone wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Showed this to an experienced senior engineer, he said it was most likely flexirest sending the data as form data.

Added `request_body_type :json` and now it's sending the correct information.

Comment: I suggest that this be a comment on the question as it is not a definitive answer.